# Splice a complex multidimentionnal array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sockets, multidimensional-array, splice

I'm using socket.io and i want to create a function to splice this form of array:

- There is an array of a string
- Each row of this array is referencing to another array, so two dimensionnal array
- Each row of this second dimention may have 0 or multiple object socket

In my case, i have this :

***Users[user_uid][socket]***, where socket is an object who have the property "uid"

I have to **create a function who properly remove a socket of the array using the UID property**. **If there are not another socket for the specific user, then i have to delete the user.**

I know that i have to use the splice property, but i really don't see how can i start

## EDIT

Exemple of data :

```
Users["user_1"] [0]{ID: 1, username: nameOfuser_1}
Users["user_1"] [1]{ID: 2, username: nameOfuser_1}
Users["user_1"] [2]{ID: 3, username: nameOfuser_1}
Users["user_2"] [0]{ID: 4, username: nameOfuser_2}
Users["user_3"] [0]{ID: 5, username: nameOfuser_3}
Users["user_3"] [1]{ID: 6, username: nameOfuser_3}
```

Want to delete object by ID. If we delete the object with ID 4, have to delete the user_2.

Obviously, everything was simplified to reflect as simple as possible my constraint.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could do a `for` loop over the array that contains the sockets. If you find a socket with a matching UID, do `splice(i, 1)` and `break`. Could you include some sample data in your question so everyone can see how it's actually structured?

Comment: Yes, i've edited that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var current in Users[uid]){
    if(current.id == object.id){
        current.splice(Users.indexOf(current), 1);
        break;
    }
}

if(Users[uid].length == 0){
    Users.splice(Users.indexOf(uid),1);
}
```